# Add Google Sign-in without using iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-api, google-signin

I'm trying to add Google Sign-in to my website following their [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button). It works fine except when I select the "Block third party cookies and site data" option in my Chrome settings

[image: chrome://settings/content]

in which case a JavaScript error is thrown with the error message

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property  from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
```

The error occurs in an iframe that the Google Auth API tries to load for the Sign-in button.

Is there a way to make it work **even if I keep the block third party cookies option selected**? Maybe there is a way to configure the Google button so that it doesn't use iframe? It seems that [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) has a similar setup and they don't use iframe. How are they doing it?

Comment: Have you tried [Google Sign-In for server side apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow)?